# Django: What is the difference between ./manage.py [...] and python manage.py [...]

Tags: python, django

I am following a tutorial for Django and at some point, it says to run `./manage.py migrate` and says that if I get an error, I should fix it.
I get an error but when I search for it I can't find specifically `./manage.py` but I keep finding mixes with that and `python manage.py`.
But when I run the code `python3 manage.py` everything works fine and I don't get errors.
So are `./manage.py` and `python(3) manage.py` different or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is the same.

Error might be because of your system configuration, for example when system does not know how to run python script, or when script has not "executable" permission set (`chmod a+x manage.py` might fix this).